# AWS RDS: Automate postgres extension installation

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, automation, amazon-rds, postgis

I have a RDS Postgres instance. I have launched this instance using CloudFormation template. I am able to add PostGIS extension on this instance.

I will be using this template to launch multiple RDS instance frequently and every time I would need PostGIS extension on the instance. Is there any way, I can automate installation of Postgres extensions on RDS.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [RDS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.PostgreSQL.CommonDBATasks.html#Appendix.PostgreSQL.CommonDBATasks.PostGIS) the only way to enable this is by running the below SQL statement.

```
create extension postgis;
CREATE EXTENSION
create extension fuzzystrmatch;
CREATE EXTENSION
create extension postgis_tiger_geocoder;
CREATE EXTENSION
create extension postgis_topology;
CREATE EXTENSION
```

For this to happen a resource needs to be able to perform the SQL statement which requires an additional resource in order to apply this statement.

CloudFormation supports [custom resources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources-lambda.html) which allow a Lambda function to perform custom functionality. This Lambda would need to be able to connect to your RDS to perform the SQL command.